# private val viewModel by lazy { ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!).get(TaskTimerViewModel::class.java) } deprecated, almost there

Tags: android, kotlin

OK so I was doing a tutorial and it had

```
private val viewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProviders.of(activity!!).get(TaskTimerViewModel::class.java) 
}
```

and I think the solution is

```
private val viewModel by lazy {
    ViewModelProvider(this)[TaskTimerViewModel::class.java] 
}
```

And this seems correct but if I replace this with activity!! in the second code fragment, it does not work.

I am fairly sure I need to use activity!! as I am sharing the ViewModel between 2 fragments.

Maybe ime doing it totally wrong.

Comment: You can just use `by activityViewModels`

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured it out.  I am using a contentProvider and as it is shared between the two fragments it does not matter that the ViewModel is not shared.